# click on floor plan regions in an iPhone app?

Tags: ios

I want to build an iPhone app that displays a floor plan of different regions/rooms.  When a user taps on a region/room, it shows the hit-state color for a fraction of a second before sliding to a new UIView with additional text information.

Should I be setting up all the different regions via UIImages or should I draw my own floor plans programmatically?  I tried drawing some rectangles programmatically, but wasn't sure if it's possible to attach tap event handlers to the graphics.  Or if it's easier to maintain floor maps with unusual shapes programmatically.

Comment: CAShapeLayers with a UITapGestureRecognizer, or even an expertly subclassed UIButton could make your life quite a bit easier.

Comment: Any luck john ? have same requirement !

Comment: I too have a similar requirement, let me know if you were able to achieve the same.

Answer (score 1):

My requirement was same like you. See my [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19727944/implement-floor-map-with-user-interaction-on-specific-region-room-area?noredirect=1#comment29376667_19727944). Finally i am go ahead with `UIScrollView` with `Zoom in out functionality`. I have add multiple `UIViews` in `Scroll` and all `UIViews` have `UILable` So it will look like `Room / Booth` and it will look like [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19728213/935381). To archive this i have face one [Query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19856928/935381) and finally resolved this and implement the **Floor Map** Like my 1st question link.

Now to resolved your question that You have to implement `UITapGestureRecognizer` like below code.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *fingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlefingerTap:)];
fingerTap.delegate = self;
[fingerTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
```

than you have to set this Gesture to your view and implement the tap method like below
`[rigionView addGestureRecognizer:fingerTap];`

```
- (void)handlefingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{}
```

If you have add multiple `UIViews` in `Scroll` than implement the above code in `for loop`.i have done the same.

I hope it will help you..